# Using the same Oracle Sequence while loading 2 tables using SQLLDR

Tags: sql-loader

I want to load the following 2 tables using the SQLLDR.
Table Structures of the 2 tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(ID varchar2(50), --PK
org_cd  varchar2(50), --PK
NAME VARCHAR2 (255),
Address1 VARCHAR2(1000),
DOB TIMESTAMP(3),
cust_ref_col number  ---used for all the future references to this record since this is a number. This is unique key.
    );

CREATE TABLE Customer_contact
(ID varchar2(50), --PK
org_cd  varchar2(50), --PK 
Contact_id Number, --PK --Running serial # for a given Customer
contact_name varchar2(50),
cust_ref_col number  ---foreign key from Customer table 
);
```

## Here is the Data File, customer.dat (the last column value of 1 is dummy since I want to generate the Oracle Sequence(partnersequence) Number

```
PTNR_78814824,ACCT,Tom,123 Church Road, 12-dec-99,1,Ralph,1
PTNR_78814825,FIN,Tom,124 Main Road, 12-dec-99,2,Jody,1
PTNR_78814826,ENGG,Tom,125 Station Road, 12-dec-99,3,Mardy,1
```

## My control File Looks like this

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE test.dat
INTO TABLE Customer
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(ID   ,
 org_cd   ,
 name     ,
 Address1 ,
 DOB      ,
 cust_ref_col   "partnersequence.nextval"
 )

INTO TABLE Customer_contact
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(ID   ,
 org_cd   ,
 Fill1 Filler,
 Fill2 Filler,
 Fill3 Filler,
 Fill4 Filler,
 cust_ref_col   "partnersequence.nextval"
)
```

Here the issue is that the cust_ref_col in Customer_contact table is getting a new sequence#. I want to use the same sequencec# generated for 
Customer table. Can you please help.

Comment: Appreciate the help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood the OP's question.  He was looking for a solution where both tables would get the same sequence number per each row (I believe answered in the comments).  This answer shows how to get a unique sequence per an entire load.  While not an answer I think the info would be helpful so I'll leave it.

As you found out already, calling your sequence.nextval in the control file causes it to increment for each row loaded.  The trick is to call a package that sets the value once upon instantiation, then call package functions that return the values for each row loaded. Since I have set this up already for my loads, I'll share with you what I did with an explanation.  Our loads add a load_date and a load_sequence_id to the tables, so that's what you'll see in these examples. Assumed is the reader understands the structure of a package already as that's too much to explain here without muddying up the main question.

You'll need to create a sequence (you have already), and a package. The package contains 2 variables to hold the load_date and load_seq_id, 2 "getter" functions to return them, and code to set them upon instantiation.  Then your control file will call the "getter" functions to return the load_date and load_seq_id from the package which will be the same for every row.

So, upon starting the load, when the first row to load calls the function to get the sequence, the package is instantiated and the date and sequence are set, then returned.  As long as the session is active the date/sequence will not change from then on and subsequent calls to the getter functions will continue to return the same values.

The package spec and body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SCHEMA.LOAD_SEQ AS
  /******************************************************************************
     NAME:       LOAD_SEQ
     PURPOSE:    Sets unique load_date and Load_seq_id per session when
                 the package is instantiated.  Package functions are
                 intended to be called from control files so all rows in a
                 file load will have the same load_date and
                 load_seq_id.

                 When the functions are called, the package is instantiated and
                 the code at the bottom is run once for the session, setting the
                 load_date and load_seq_id.  The functions simply return the values
                 which will remain the same for that session.

    load_date   date "MM/DD/YYYY" "to_char(trunc(schema.load_seq.get_load_date), 'mm/dd/yyyy')",
    load_seq_id decimal external "schema.load_seq.get_load_seq_id"
                 (each row then has the same load_seq_id).

     REVISIONS:
     Ver        Date        Author           Description
     ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
     1.0        2/20/2017   Gary_W           1. Created this package.
  ******************************************************************************/
  NEXT_LOAD_SEQ_ID NUMBER;
  NEXT_LOAD_DATE   DATE;

  FUNCTION GET_LOAD_SEQ_ID
    RETURN NUMBER;

  FUNCTION GET_LOAD_DATE
    RETURN DATE;
END THC_LOAD_SEQ;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SCHEMA.LOAD_SEQ AS
  /******************************************************************************
     NAME:       GET_LOAD_SEQ_ID
     PURPOSE:    Return the package variable LOAD_SEQ.NEXT_LOAD_SEQ_ID
                 which is set when the package is instantiated.  It does not
                 change during the session.

     REVISIONS:
     Ver        Date        Author           Description
     ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
     1.0        2/20/2017   Gary_W           1. Created this package.
  ******************************************************************************/
  FUNCTION GET_LOAD_SEQ_ID
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN LOAD_SEQ.NEXT_LOAD_SEQ_ID;
  END GET_LOAD_SEQ_ID;

  /******************************************************************************
     NAME:       GET_LOAD_DATE
     PURPOSE:    Return the package variable LOAD_SEQ.NEXT_LOAD_DATE
                 which is set when the package is instantiated.  It does not
                 change during the session.

     REVISIONS:
     Ver        Date        Author           Description
     ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
     1.0        2/20/2017    Gary_W          1. Created this package.
  ******************************************************************************/
  FUNCTION GET_LOAD_DATE
    RETURN DATE IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN LOAD_SEQ.NEXT_LOAD_DATE;
  END GET_LOAD_DATE;
BEGIN
    -- Code outside of the procedures/functions defined in the spec runs 
    -- once on instantiation of the package, when the package is first called by the session.
    -- It sets the package variables which then do not change during the life of the session.
    SELECT SYSDATE, partnersequence.NEXTVAL
    INTO   LOAD_SEQ.NEXT_LOAD_DATE, LOAD_SEQ.NEXT_LOAD_SEQ_ID
    FROM   DUAL;
END LOAD_SEQ;
/
```

In your control file:

```
LOAD_DATE      date "MM/DD/YYYY" "to_char(trunc(schema.load_seq.get_load_date), 'mm/dd/yyyy')"
cust_ref_col   "decimal external "schema.load_seq.get_load_seq_id""
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion, Gary...Let me incorporate the same and test it...

Comment: Gary, I am sorry if I was not clear on my requirement. I want to create a new sequence # per record (not for the entire session). So for a given row (in the data file) a sequence #(say 1001) will be used by Customer and Customer_contact table. while processing the next record(from the data file), next sequence #(1002) will be used. Will you please help here...

Comment: .In essence, I want to use the generated sequence # for 2 tables (Customer and Customer_contact) since the Sequence # is a Unique key in Customer table and the same is a Foreign Key in Customer_contact table

Comment: D'oh!  In that case I think you can use partnersequence.currval (current value) for the Customer_contact table.  I didn't test this though.  Please report back if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion, Gary. Appreciate it...I used it(that was my first thought). But since I am migrating one company (stored within a Customer) at a time to prod, the Currval may not be same if Customers are being created (for a different company) when the the current company's migration is going on.

Comment: The last option I was thinking is to write a trigger on Customer_contact and populate cust_ref_col  from Customer...Always, appreciate your feedback.